# nvidia visual profiler Encountered invalid option : --openacc-profiling

Tags: cuda, profiling, nsight, nvprof

Running a simple application on nvidia Visual Profiler shows the error:

```
Encountered invalid option : --openacc-profiling
======== Use "nvprof --help" to get more information.
```

Any gpu applicatiion I try to profile gets the same error.

I tried to uncheck the option "Enable OpenACC profiling" and got the same error.

Versions:

```
nvprof --version
nvprof: NVIDIA (R) Cuda command line profiler
Copyright (c) 2013 - 2014 NVIDIA Corporation
Release version 6.5.14 (21)
```

And

```
NVIDIA Visual Profiler
Version: 6.5
```

Comment: You may have a corrupted configuration -- a newer version of `nvvp` attempting to use an older version of `nvprof`, for example.  Which version of `nvvp` are you using?  Are you on linux or windows?  What is the reported version of `nvprof` when you invoke it from a command line?

Comment: The `nvvp` version you are using is not version 6.5  Version 6.5 did not have a checkbox for "Enable OpenACC profiling".  You have a mixed or corrupted configuration.

Comment: The "Enable OpenACC profiling" checkbox did not appear until [CUDA 8](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-8-features-revealed/).  When you have `nvvp` open which has that OpenACC checkbox, do Help...About Visual Profiler to find out the version.

Comment: You're right @robert-crovella it looks like I have two versions of nvvp instaled 6.5 and 8.0, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears (based on comments above) that the issue here was a mixed configuration - a CUDA 8 version of `nvvp` (the visual profiler) calling a CUDA 6.5 version of `nvprof`.

The visual profiler performs some of its work by calling `nvprof` to do low-level profiling.  As a result, it is passing command-line switches to `nvprof`, and so `nvprof` is expected to match, version-wise, the version of `nvvp` that is being used.  If that is not the case, problems like this can occur.

The solution is to have a consistent install.  It should be possible to have both CUDA 6.5 and CUDA 8 installed on the same machine, but it's necessary for the `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables to be [set in such a way](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#environment-setup) that the CUDA 8 version of `nvvp` will find/invoke the CUDA 8 version of `nvprof`, for example.  Generally, the instructions contained in the [linux install guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#environment-setup) for setting of these variables should be sufficient, but care should be taken, for example, to be sure that there is not some previous version of `nvprof` that will be found due to the `PATH` setting when using CUDA 8.  It's not possible cover all the possible ways in which this may happen, so some rudimentary linux administration skills will be necessary to ensure such a configuration is internally consistent.

Otherwise, if these skills don't exist, the [linux install instructions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#handle-uninstallation) may provide the best solution - remove all previous versions of CUDA when installing a new version.  That is another possible approach which, if done correctly, should absolutely prevent a problem such as this from occurring.